# 7 liter and 5 liter jugs to 4 liter jug puzzle with depth-first search

Tags: prolog, water-jug-problem

I want to use any kind of depth-first search to solve the 7 Liter and 5 Liter to 4 Liter Puzzle in SWI-Prolog

I have no idea how I could start..

I want to get 4 Liters in a Jug at the end

```
solve(JUG1, JUG2) :- fill(JUG1, JUG2), swap(JUG1, JUG2).
fill(JUG1,JUG2) :- JUG1 = 7, JUG2 = 5.
%i dont know about that
swap(JUG1, JUG2) :- JUG1 = JUG2.
```

Comment: For fun, **after** you find your own solution, encode the problem using Logtalk's *state-space search framework* example  at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/searching and play with the provided alternative search methods, try some heuristics, and get performance stats on the different variations. You will also find there other traditional state-space search problems like missionaries and cannibals or bridge crossing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem to solve and I found my code on my PC for that:

We are using iterative deepening depth-first search to combine the advantages of a breath and depth search. With the following code we are trying possible combinations to reach our goal which is 4 liter at the end in one jug. If we find a solution we will print it accordingly.

```erlang
% Iterative deepening depth-first search
dlDfs(Node, Path, DepthLimit, ReturnPath) :-
    goal(Node), reverse(Path, ReturnPath);
    DepthLimit > 0,
    adj(Node,NewNeighbor), not(member(NewNeighbor,Path)),
    L is DepthLimit-1,
    dlDfs(NewNeighbor, [NewNeighbor|Path], L, ReturnPath).

idDfsLoop(Start, D, ReturnPath) :-
    dlDfs(Start, [Start], D, ReturnPath)
    ;
    L is D+1,
    idDfsLoop(Start, L, ReturnPath).

idDfs(Start, ReturnPath) :- idDfsLoop(Start, 1, ReturnPath).

% [L,R] L is 7 liter, R is 5 liter
goal([_,4]).
goal([4,_]).

adj(X,Y) :- adj0(X,Y).

%fill up
adj0([X,Y],[7,Y]).
adj0([X,Y],[X,5]).

%Swap over to another canister
adj0([X,Y],[Z,U]) :- X+Y =< 5, Z is 0, U is X+Y ; X+Y > 5, Z is (X+Y) mod 5, U is 5.
adj0([X,Y],[Z,U]) :- X+Y =< 7, Z is X+Y, U is 0 ; X+Y > 7, Z is 7, U is (X+Y) mod 7.

%empty the cansiter
adj0([X,Y],[0,Y]).
adj0([X,Y],[X,0]).

solution(Start, Return) :- idDfs(Start, Return).
```

You can call the solution predicate as following:

```erlang
solution([0,0], R)
```

One of the solutions should be for example

```erlang
R = [[0, 0], [7, 0], [2, 5], [2, 0], [0, 2], [7, 2], [4, 5]]
```

If you have any questions feel free to answer.

Comment: @lover1212121 It has following functions: 1. fill up the canister, it doesnt matter how much is in the canister (e.g. 2 Liter) its always able to fill it up to the maximum (7 or 5) 2. it swaps with the other canister if e.g. the first canister has 3 liter and the second 2 liter you can put all of it from the first in the second and the other way around too, if there would be remainings the mod operation checks for that. 3. emptys the canister it doesnt matter how much liter you have in a canister you can always empty it and put it to 0. With the search we go through all possible positions.

Comment: @A.A. your `adj0` definition is erroneous: `adj0([7,4], [6,5])` must hold, while `adj0([7,4], [1,5])` mustn't (pouring from a full 7 jug into the 5 jug with 4 liters in it). IOW it's not `mod`, it's just simple `-` that should be there.

Comment: @lover1212121 `adj0` is the "one_move" predicate: `adj0(A,B)` describes a one step change to our state: we start with `A=[L1,R1]` jugs, and end up with `B=[L2,R2]` where `Li`, `Ri` is amount of liters of water in the "left" (i.e. 7 liters capacity) and "right" (i.e. 5 liters capacity) jug, before and after the move, i.e. some action we take -- like filling up a jug, or pouring water from one jug into the other until the jug becomes empty or the other one becomes full, or emptying a jug.